# Fill combobox with selected data from datagridcolumn

Tags: c#, combobox, datagrid

My combobox is filled with two options. In my datagrid those two options are shown several times in a column. If I select one row from my datagrid, I want my combobox to show the same value as the column from the selected row in my datagrid.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

capture the cell value on SelectionChanged Event and set this value as "SelectedValue" for your combobox